# Calling function from another class in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So this is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

x = 1

Builder.load_string("""

<One>:
    name: "one"
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        Button:
            text: "Start"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "two"
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: "0"

<Two>:
    name: "two"
    Button:
        text: "Restart"
        on_release: 
            app.one.add()
            root.callotherfunction()
""")

class One(Screen):
    def add(self):
        global x
        x = x+1
        self.ids.lbl.text = str(x)
        sm.current = "one"
        print(str(x))

class Two(Screen):
    def callotherfunction(self):
        One().add()
        One().ids.lbl.text = "Two"

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(One(name='one'))
sm.add_widget(Two(name='two'))

class MyMainApp(App):
    one = One()
    two = Two()
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

What I am trying to do is update the label in Screen One from Screen Two. I have tried two different methods to call the add function, those being:

```
app.one.add()
root.callotherfunction()
```

Both of these get through and are able to change the screen and print the updated x value; however, they are not successful at updating the label.

I've also tried to change the label from the other class like this:

```
One().ids.lbl.text = "Two"
```

Again, the label does not change. If I could get any of these methods to work I would be happy. I'm newer to Kivy and trying to learn, so I appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `One().<attribute>` because each time you do, you are creating a new temporary instance, which instantly goes away.  You need to get to the original `one` and `two` instances.  I'll rework it and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you create new instances of your classes each time you call `One()` and `Two()`.  I am not a fan of globals, but here's a quickly reworked version of your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

x = 1

Builder.load_string("""

<One>:
    name: "one"
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        Button:
            text: "Start"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "two"
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: "0"

<Two>:
    name: "two"
    Button:
        text: "Restart"
        on_release:
            root.callotherfunction()
""")

class One(Screen):
    def add(self):
        global x
        x = x+1
        self.ids.lbl.text = str(x)
        sm.current = "one"
        print(str(x))

class Two(Screen):
    def callotherfunction(self):
        one.add()
        #one.ids.lbl.text = "Two"

sm = ScreenManager()
one=One(name='one')
two=Two(name='two')
sm.add_widget(one)
sm.add_widget(two)

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: It makes more sense to initialize x to zero rather than 1, because your initial label is initialized to "0".

Comment: So when you establish one and two as their respective classes before creating the widget, that is what makes it so that I'm not creating temporary instances? And you're totally right about the initial x value, this is a proof of concept more than application.

Comment: When I/you create `one=One(name='one')` in the main program, it is creating a single instance called one, which is accessible to all the functions.